# react responsive carousel no pausa el video cuando hago slide

Tags: reactjs, carrusel

Hola estoy haciendo un `carousel` con imágenes y videos con `react responsive carousel` pero al momento de ver el video y seguir con el `slide` a otra imágenes o videos, este se sigue reproduciendo, no pausa.

Intente ponerle a mi etiqueta video un `href` y hacer una función con `onchange` para que lo pause mediante `video.pause()`, pero no lo logre con ello, intente ponerlo en el atributo `onSwipeMove` pero tampoco funciono.

Adjunto el código de mi `carousel`

```
export const Carousel2 = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const property = housesData.find((house) => {
    return house.id === parseInt(id);
  });
  const list = property.images;


  return (
    <div className="card">
      <ReactCarousel
        showArrows={true}
        showStatus={false}
        swipeable={true}
        showIndicators={false}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        emulateTouch={true}
        useKeyboardArrows
        
      >
        {list.map((prop, id) => (
          <div className="image-wrapper" key={id}>
            {prop.type === "video" ? (
              <video muted controls autoPlay >
                <source src={prop.src} type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            ) : (
              <img src={prop.src} alt="media" />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}

      </ReactCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: y porque intentaste con ``href`` y no con una ``ref`` de react? Creo que estaba bien encaminada tu idea.

Comment: Tal vez no lo hice bien, en mi etiqueta video puse lo siguiente  `ref={video} onChange={handlePause}`  luego mi funcion `handlePause` tenia `video.pause()` pero igualmente el video seguia reproduciendose, a lo mejor me hace falta algo para que funcione pero no logro saber que es

Comment: si haces un console de video que te sale? Porque normalmente para acceder a una referencia tenes que acceder a ``nombreReferencia.current``, entonces creo que la funcion seria ``video.current.pause()`` en lugar de ``video.pause()``

Comment: por otro lado, tendrias que tener un console.log en la funcion ``handlePause`` para ver en que momento estas disparando esa funcion. No entiendo porque hacer click para cambiar el slide deberia ejecutar un ``onChange`` en el video (si funciona y ejecuta el console, perfecto, tu idea sirve). A lo que me refiero con esto, es que creo que el onChange deberia ir en el slider y no en el video. Y siempre que se haga un click para cambiar de slide, ahi pausar los videos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo hice funcionar, ya publique la solución

Comment: De nada! Y esa solucion que pusiste no te arroja un error en consola cada vez que el slide esta mostrando una imagen en lugar de un video, y cambias de slide? Porque la referencia al video no existiria. En ese caso lo solucionas haciendo ``const handlePause = ()=> videoRef && videoRef.current && videoRef.current.pause();`` de esta forma el pause solo se ejecutaría cuando haya un video en el DOM

Comment: No, ningún error me sale en consola, igual muchas gracias por tu mejora

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar dicho problema use un `ref` para mi etiqueta video

```
const videoRef = useRef(null)
<video  ref={videoRef}  muted controls autoPlay >
    <source src={prop.src} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Y en mi carousel agregar un onChange pasandole la función para pausar dicho video

```
onChange={handlePause}

  <ReactCarousel
   onChange={handlePause}>

  const handlePause = ()=> {
    videoRef.current.pause();
  }
```

Y ya funciono de manera correcta adjunto el código completo

```
export const Carousel2 = () => {
const videoRef = useRef(null)
  const { id } = useParams();
  const property = housesData.find((house) => {
    return house.id === parseInt(id);
  });
  const list = property.images;

  const handlePause = ()=> {
    videoRef.current.pause();
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <ReactCarousel
        showArrows={true}
        showStatus={false}
        swipeable={true}
        showIndicators={false}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        emulateTouch={true}
        useKeyboardArrows
       onChange={handlePause}
      >
        {list.map((prop, id) => (
          <div className="image-wrapper" key={id}>
            {prop.type === "video" ? (
              <video  ref={videoRef}  muted controls autoPlay >
                <source src={prop.src} type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            ) : (
              <img src={prop.src} alt="media" />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}

      </ReactCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```